# Creating a table in a database of a connection and retrieving data from another connection

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database

So I came up with a situation where I need to create a table on a database (Connection 1) and need to fill it up with data from another connection (Connection 2).

Right now I am creating these tables and filling them up with a select query in the same server using this example: `CREATE TABLE table 1 as SELECT * FROM database.dataTable`, However I am stuck to Create `table1` in a database in (Connection 1) and filling it up from (Connection 2).

To explain my self better I need to do something like this `CREAT TABLE table1(Connection 1) as SELECT * FROM database.dataTable(Connection 2)`. I am using python.

Answer (score 0):

Create table as select is done as a single operation. You can't do that with 2 connections. If you still need to do it by using 2 connections, you will have to create the table in one then, once the table exists, fill it with the second one. It doesn't look optimal.